# Find matching uniqueId between array with id's and array with objects and same id's

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, unique-id

I have the following object and array that have matching Id's but because of a drag and drop feature a simple map without a find doesn't work, because they are not matching in order. I will explain.

I have this object (which is my updated values after a form submit)

`data` variable in my code below

```
{"we98Yt8JLyxkcJorf":"Kanye","yG6JiFaBBut6XgHpj":"2813348004","RcpDcF72K2aN9fub4":"kanye@usa.gov","ShBTee9MNxvRNG3XN":"123 White House Avenue","GSCZMMwscKh3ZaKix":"473 estate drive","Jmr7HoYmfXJWHMwmr":"2813348004"}
```

and I have this array with objects in them that correspond to the ids

`cards` variable in my code below

```
[{"inputType":"shortText","uniId":"we98Yt8JLyxkcJorf","label":"First Name:","value":"Kanye"},{"inputType":"phoneNumber","uniId":"yG6JiFaBBut6XgHpj","label":"Cell Phone Number","value":"2813348004"},{"inputType":"email","uniId":"RcpDcF72K2aN9fub4","label":"Work Email","value":"kanye@usa.gov"},{"inputType":"multipleChoice","uniId":"GSCZMMwscKh3ZaKix","label":"Preferred Method of Contact","value":"2813348004","options":[{"uniId":"poXf65zi8NDko5Je4","label":"Email"},{"uniId":"FmvYT4cbY8JotAaqA","label":"Cell Phone"}]},{"inputType":"Address","uniId":"ShBTee9MNxvRNG3XN","label":"Home Address","value":"123 White House Avenue"},{"inputType":"dropDown","uniId":"Jmr7HoYmfXJWHMwmr","label":"How did you find us?","value":"2813348004","options":[{"uniId":"EQj9MXdnaBjmCkAKZ","label":"Google"},{"uniId":"EbbhhqSd4K6sAsQ3T","label":"Referral"}]}]
```

Now I want to update the array with the new data, there is a uniqueId field on both of them that match, but I keep failing at trying to match them and update the array so I can submit that to the db in the format it needs ot be which is it's current state.

This is what I have tried thus far it returns undefined

```
   const test = Object.keys(data);

    console.log(test);

    let testArray = [];

    test.map((item) => {
      let testArraySingle = cards.find((x) => {
        x.uniId === item;
      }).value;

      testArray.push(testArraySingle);
    });

    console.log(testArray);
```

I have tried this also but it returns incorrect because it only matches it loops how many times of the array.length but doesnt keep checking, if that makes sense

```
const dataArray = Object.entries(data);

    let newArray = [];

    cards.map((card, i) => {
      var checkId = dataArray[i][0];

      let matchesArray = [];

      if (card.uniId === checkId) {
        const new_obj = { ...cards[i], value: dataArray[i][1] };
        newArray.push(new_obj);
      }
      // }
    });
```

Hope somebody can help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use combination of `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.map()` method to get your result. Traverse data keys using map and filter uniId by filter method and again use map to get the all the values.

```js
const data = {
  we98Yt8JLyxkcJorf: 'Kanye',
  yG6JiFaBBut6XgHpj: '2813348004',
  RcpDcF72K2aN9fub4: 'kanye@usa.gov',
  ShBTee9MNxvRNG3XN: '123 White House Avenue',
  GSCZMMwscKh3ZaKix: '473 estate drive',
  Jmr7HoYmfXJWHMwmr: '2813348004',
};

const cards = [
  {
    inputType: 'shortText',
    uniId: 'we98Yt8JLyxkcJorf',
    label: 'First Name:',
    value: 'Kanye',
  },
  {
    inputType: 'phoneNumber',
    uniId: 'yG6JiFaBBut6XgHpj',
    label: 'Cell Phone Number',
    value: '2813348004',
  },
  {
    inputType: 'email',
    uniId: 'RcpDcF72K2aN9fub4',
    label: 'Work Email',
    value: 'kanye@usa.gov',
  },
  {
    inputType: 'multipleChoice',
    uniId: 'GSCZMMwscKh3ZaKix',
    label: 'Preferred Method of Contact',
    value: '2813348004',
    options: [
      { uniId: 'poXf65zi8NDko5Je4', label: 'Email' },
      { uniId: 'FmvYT4cbY8JotAaqA', label: 'Cell Phone' },
    ],
  },
  {
    inputType: 'Address',
    uniId: 'ShBTee9MNxvRNG3XN',
    label: 'Home Address',
    value: '123 White House Avenue',
  },
  {
    inputType: 'dropDown',
    uniId: 'Jmr7HoYmfXJWHMwmr',
    label: 'How did you find us?',
    value: '2813348004',
    options: [
      { uniId: 'EQj9MXdnaBjmCkAKZ', label: 'Google' },
      { uniId: 'EbbhhqSd4K6sAsQ3T', label: 'Referral' },
    ],
  },
];

const ret = Object.keys(data)
  .map((x) => {
    const tmp = cards
      .filter((y) => y.uniId === x)
      .map((z) => {
        const obj = { ...z };
        obj.value = data[x];
        return obj;
      });
    return tmp;
  })
  .flat();
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: hmm, what that data I want in the end is the same format of the cards array with the values updated from data, for example I want the id GSCZMMwscKh3ZaKix form the data value `473 estate drive` to update that uniId's value object in the cards array so it would be`[... {inputType:'multipleChoice',unId:GSCZMMwscKh3ZaKix,value:473 estate drive}...]` For that I'd your result still has the number 2183348004 but data variable has the updated value which is `473 estate drive` for the value. And I want the entire array at the end with every object in it as the result.